# onSaveInstanceState on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, position

I self haven't experienced this crash but some users does get it, when I check the Firebase Crashlytics.

So I have a Recyclerview and this small piece of code does save the position.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
Parcelable state;
```

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        state = layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
    }
```

```
    public void jsonrequest() {

        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, response -> {
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            lstUserCard.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    UserCard userCard = new UserCard();
                    userCard.setfName(jsonObject.getString("fname"));
                    userCard.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                    lstUserCard.add(userCard);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, lstUserCard) ;
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);
            layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }, error -> {
            return;
        });


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DashBoardActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

which just works fine for me but it does crash for some users.

the error in the Firebase:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()' on a null object reference
> com.app.myapp.DashBoardActivity.onPause

And the error line is:

> state = layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();

The method jsonrequest, is called in onResume(), there is nothing inside the onCreate.

Do I have to put some code in the onCreate? would like to see some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NullPointerException` layoutManager==null. Create a layout manager first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time `onPause()` is called your `layoutManager` is not initialized yet, because you only initialize it in the `Response.Listener` you pass to `JsonArrayRequest`. So you get the exception if you quickly navigate away from your `Activity`.

You can solve it by initializing it with a default value or doing a `null` check. Also I recommend reading up about [saving state](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states) in Android, because your approach is not working.